# Powershell - Loop through folder, Get Contents and post to SOAP

Tags: powershell

I am trying to loop through a folder, grab all files, read their contents then post each file content individually to SOAP.

This is how I would do it, but PowerShell returns an error.

```
Invoke-Webrequest : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

Below is my code:

```
$dataAPI = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\..\Output'
$uri = 'http://server-name.com:8080/name/name2'

ForEach ($Item in $dataAPI) {
    Get-Content $Item.FullName | Invoke-Webrequest -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"; "SOAPAction" = "http://server-name.com:8080/name/name2"} -Method 'POST' -Body $dataAPI -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential 

}
```

I am not really sure where I should place the Invoke-WebRequest...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am curious to what error you get?  Shouldn't it be ```$answer = Get-content | $item.fullname ...``` ? Then in that same for each loop do the ```webrequest``` with the ```$answer```

Comment: Hi. I have tried that and It's not updating the database as intended. 
Code I have used

<code>


`
ForEach ($Item in $dataAPI) {
    $answer = Get-Content $Item.FullName 
    Invoke-Webrequest -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"; "SOAPAction" = "http://some-website:8080/url1/url1"} -Method 'POST' -Body $answer -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential 

}

</code>

Comment: What is the error ? I am pretty sure it goes ```$Answer = get-content | ``` what you wrote above is missing a ```|```

Comment: The error I am seeing is in the initial post.

Where exactly do you mean to add that pipeline?

Comment: Opps sorry about that.  ```$answer = Get-content | $item.fullname``` note what you wrote is missing that ```|``` between ```get-content``` and ```$item```

Comment: `$answer = Get-Content $Item.FullName` will make `$answer` an **array** of lines. Try `$answer = Get-Content $Item.FullName -Raw` so that you get a single multiline string instead of an array in the body. Also, you do not want a pipe `|` after that, but a semi-colon `;` to denote these are two separate commands. (and of course use `-Body $answer`, not `-Body $dataAPI`)

Comment: So I have tried `Get-Content $Item.FullName -Raw` + the `;` and that didn't work either. No changes were made to the database. I think the problem lies with Get-ChildItems or the loop? I have tried to process a file with a pre-defined name and it worked perfectly.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` without the `-File` flag will also pick up any subfolders in the path and Get-Content won't work on a folder of course.. Be more specific there, something like `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Gabriel\Output' -Filter '*.xml' -File` (or whatever extension your files use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing from my comments,

- Add switch `-Raw` to the Get-Content call to receive a single multiline string instead of an array of lines
- Add switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem call to ensure you will only deal with files in the loop, not directories too

Try

```
# if all files you need have a common extension, add `-Filter '*.xml'` to below line
# '*.xml' is just an example here..
$files  = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\Gabriel\Output' -File
$uri    = 'http://server-name.com:8080/name/name2'
$header = @{"Content-Type" = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"; "SOAPAction" = "http://server-name.com:8080/name/name2"}

foreach ($Item in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content $Item.FullName -Raw
    Invoke-Webrequest -Headers $header -Method 'POST' -Body $content -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential 
}
```

Comment: Adding that `Invoke-WebRequest` does allow `-Body` to be piped in as a string.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you !